# How can i work jar file in terminal?

Tags: java

I studying Create and work Jar file, but it's not work.

this is code,

```
    package chapterthirteen;

    /** 
     * @author user01
     * 銀行を表すクラス。
     */

    public class Bank {
        /**
         * 銀行の名前
         */
        String name;
        /**
         * 銀行の住所s
         */
        String address;
        /**
         * 口座を追加する。
         * @param owner 口座名義人
         * @param initialBalance 初期残高
         */
        public void addAccount(String owner, int initialBalance) {

        }
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println("試験用のメインメソッドです。");
        }
    }
```

this is Manifest.txt what I typing

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Main-Class: chapterthirteen.Bank
```

this is Terminal Text

```
    admin-no-MacBook-Air:chapterthirteen user01$ jar -cvmf manifest.txt Bank.jar Bank.class
    マニフェストが追加されました
    Bank.classを追加中です(入=776)(出=486)(37%収縮されました)
    admin-no-MacBook-Air:chapterthirteen user01$ java -jar Bank.jar
    Bank.jarにメイン・マニフェスト属性がありません
    admin-no-MacBook-Air:chapterthirteen user01$
```

and, this is Menifest.MF(unzip file)

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Main-Class: chapterthirteen.Bank
    Created-By: 9.0.4 (Oracle Corporation)
```

what is problem? and how can I working JAR file in terminal?

=================================================

for reference, I already know how can making JAR file in eclipse.

I just want to know, Create and Work JAR in terminal(for studying)

plz help me.

=================================================

translate in terminal

```
jar -cvmf manifest.txt Bank.jar Bank.class

マニフェストが追加されました 
-> Manifestation has been added.

Bank.classを追加中です(入=776)(出=486)(37%収縮されました)
->Bank.Class is added.(in=776)(exit=486)(37 % contracted)

java -jar Bank.jar

Bank.jarにメイン・マニフェスト属性がありません
->Bank.jar does not have the main manifestos attribute.

admin-no-MacBook-Air:chapterthirteen user01$
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run the jar?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: `jar cmvf META-INF/MANIFEST.MF <new-jar-filename>.jar  <files to include>`

Comment: You have everything correct **except** the *path*. Your `Bank` class must be in a folder named `chapterthirteen` in the JAR.

Comment: thank you guys! I create in my package, and it work!
it's path Problem to work class! specially thanks Elliott Frisch!